# nav button not closing the menu when clicked again

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have searched a lot, but havent found a simple solution for the problem. 
When you click the button it opens and do not close again, any suggestion of what can be missing? Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="midia/logo.jpg" alt="Tutto Piccolo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#sobre">Sobre a Tutto</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#colecao">Coleção</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contato">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#cliente">Área do Cliente</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When I put the code in code pen it does close and open the navbar correctly.
Demo pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Papmjb
Can you please show us your full code?

Answer (score 1):

In [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), it states that

> Navbars can utilize .navbar-toggler, .navbar-collapse, and .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} classes to change when their content collapses behind a button. In combination with other utilities, you can easily choose when to show or hide particular elements.
>
> For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand class.

So, change `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">` to `<nav class="navbar sticky-top">`

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/3eux74yj/) example.

Comment: I ve tried what youve suggested, but it didnt worked

Comment: @AnaliseBurtet I work. I add a jsfiddle example for you, may be it is clear. Besides, I changed the nav-toggler to nav-toggle, so as to show the button.

Comment: @AnaliseBurtet If you still have problem, then you need to provide more css setting, your bootstrap version, and even jquery version.